# Magento update inventory via REST api

Tags: magento, restful-url

I have a megento ecommerce site. I also have another inventory using in my factory. I want to update the product inventory by calling magento API from my factory inventory.

I found some solution using OAUTH. But it need authorization key and some secret key for updating inventory of magento site. But I need one time key, so that I can communicate with magento site life time.